# Не запускается jar при сбоке из другой директории

Tags: java, jar

```
.
└── src
    ├── META-INF
    │   └── MANIFEST.MF
    └── com
        └── company
            └── Main.java
```

Main.java:

```
package com.company;
  
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.company.Main
```

Выполняю из папки src

```
javac com/company/Main.java 
jar -cvfm out.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF com/company/*.class
java -jar out.jar
```

Всё ок

Но если из уровня выше:

```
javac src/com/company/Main.java 
jar -cvfm out.jar src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF src/com/company/*.class
java -jar out.jar
```

То получаю:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.Main
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите запускать `jar` в таком виде то вам нужно добавить `package src.com.company;` в классе и `Main-Class: src.com.company.Main` в манифесте. Тогда все будет работать как задумано.

А если же отталкиваться от того что у вас в файлах:
Когда вы создаете `jar`, первый каталог пакета (в основном `com`), должен быть первым в архиве, а вы должны находиться уровнем выше него (как раз в `src`, в нашем случае) ибо в противном случае в архив попадает все что ниже. Например: когда вы архивировали с уровня выше то в архив попадала директория `src`, которая из за этого превращалась в его первый уровень. Но в манифесте прописано что в пути `com/company/Main.java` первой будет директория `com` и при из за этого обращении к main файлу ничего не находится.

Кстати. Папку `META-INF` самому делать не обязательно. Архиватор генерирует её саму и создает там `MANIFEST.MF` скопировав туда данные из указанного вами манифеста.

Я не эксперт в этой теме, но объяснил как мог и сам понимаю. Надеюсь с какими-нибудь вопросами помог.